# Delete same value in multiple table in one PDO query ?

Tags: php, mysql

memo_info table memo_no and memo_item table memo_no and memo_price table memo_no if all memo no 600 then in single query delete all values from this 3 tables. How can i do that ?

Comment: which database server you are using?

Comment: wampserver can be used

Comment: so I suppose it's mysql

Comment: yes i do that . Something else ?

Comment: just run your 3 queries on 3 separate calls

Comment: yes it can done , but i want to delete all of this in only a single query , u can suggest me any way ?

Comment: No, because it's just a groundless whim.

Comment: No it's not this type , i think it is a fun step to perform all of this in one single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to do it the right way, you must have to set [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with a "cascade delete" option set on the two "table2" and "table3" while making it an index key in table1, as in your case "memo_no" is the column, so when you delete record from table 1, the other two will automatically be deleted on which a foreign key constraint is set.
Second possible way to do is by using PDO transaction you can do it like,

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE memo_no = 600;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE memo_no = 600;
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE memo_no = 600;
COMMIT;
```

or Alternatively you can do it like so, 
Note :
write down the following query in PDO prepare and bind the value of memo_no, i have given you the working example below,

```
DELETE a.*, b.* ,c.*
    FROM tbl1 a 
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 b 
    ON b.memo_no = a.memo_no 
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 c
    ON c.memo_no =b.memo_no 
    WHERE a.memo_no = 600
```

Comment: it's 3 query but i  want this only one query

Comment: Then you have to follow the first suggestion as i said, set foreign key constraint on "memo_no" column in two tables with cascade delete option set on it, so when you run a single query of deletion the from let say "tbl1", the other two records will automatically be deleted from "tbl2" and "tbl3".

Comment: @NazmulHossain you can check out, i have edited the answer.

Comment: What can be defined by a , b , c ?

Comment: @NazmulHossain Those are aliases for table names, You can read more about  [SQL Aliase](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)